# Xamarin StackLayout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to learn the basics of Xamarin App Development and when I am running this code on my phone it doesn't show me any label

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        Color[] colors = { Color.White, Color.Silver, Color.Gray, Color.Blue, Color.Red, Color.DarkBlue, Color.Black, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.OrangeRed, Color.Orange };
        string[] colorNames = { "White", "Silver", "Gray", "Blue", "Red", "DarkBlue", "Black", "Yellow", "Green", "OrangeRed", "Orange" };
        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label
            {
                Text = colorNames[i],
                TextColor = colors[i],
                FontSize=Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large,typeof(Label))
            };
            stackLayout.Children.Add(label);
        }
        this.Content = stackLayout;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Your code looks fine, assuming your Application subclass (`App` if you created the project via a template) is setting the `MainPage` to this MainPage class? `MainPage = new MainPage();`

Comment: I forgot to instantiate the MainPage class, lol

Comment: Been there, done that  ;-)